# How do I delete/replace the common suffix of the list of files names in Linux?

Tags: bash

I had something like 100 *.txt files.

I want to remove/replace the suffix of txt files.

How I do it in LINUX.

```
Example:
1_S9_001.f.txt
2_S13_001.f.txt
3_S23_001.f.txt
4_S45_001.f.txt
5_S90_001.f.txt

Changing the file name:
1_S9.txt
2_S13.txt
3_S23.txt
4_S45.txt
5_S90.txt 

Renaming:
1_S9_rt.txt
2_S13_rt.txt
3_S23_rt.txt
4_S45_rt.txt
5_S90_rt.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the system, the behaviour of the `rename` command can be quite different. Check the `man` page for details.

The first type is simpler and you just tell it what string to replace and what string to replace it with:

```
rename _001.f ""  *_001.f.txt
rename _001.f _rt *_001.f.txt
```

The second type uses Perl substitution:

```
rename 's/_001\.f//'    *_001.f.txt
rename 's/_001\.f/_rt/' *_001.f.txt
```

Or you can use a loop and parameter expansion to construct the new names yourself:

```
for f in *_001.f.txt ; do
    mv "$f" "${f%_001.f.txt}".txt
    mv "$f" "${f%_001.f.txt}"_rt.txt
done
```

The `%` means "Remove from the right", `#` is used similarly to remove from the left.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if I understood you correctly. The following code renames your "Example" files to "Renaming" files:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's/001.f/rt/')";done
```